# Android: accessing variable inside and outside loop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access variable "key" from inner most loop loop. But unable to, I have checked other posts about accessing variables in inner classes and followed methods like declaring it final and make it a global variable but none work.

Please check the below code and suggest me.

In the following code I can see toast message of user key inside the loop, Howevver toast message outside loop is giving empty string.

```
 private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUserDetails;

public static String key = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    --- some code ---

    mDatabaseUserID = DatabaseUtils.getDatabase().getReference().child("Users").child(user_id);

    mDatabaseUserID.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot accountSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                key = accountSnapshot.getKey().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[Basically I need this key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xhnr.png)

Comment: When method onCreate() getting called, value of key is not changed so the toast shows the empty string only, here order of execution matters

Comment: Please put your firebase database

Comment: Actually as mentioned in the post toast inside the loop is showing value where as toast which is out side the loop is not returning any value.
Main point here is I would retrieve key value.

Answer (score 1):

Because the loop hasn't been run yet.  The loop is in a value event listener.  It won't be run until later, when the DatabaseReference calls it.